# Can I incorporate prototype.js into an FBML facebook application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, prototypejs, fbml, scriptaculous

we have a lot of existing code in a web application that we want to use in a facebook application. Much of it on the client side depends on prototype.js.

Can I incorporate prototype.js into my FB application without difficulty, and am I going to have to make a choice about iFrame vs FBML early on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to choose between iFrame or FBML early on; in fact, it's generally the first thing you do. If you go with iFrame, you may use whatever JavaScript library you like. FBML, on the other hand, is very restricted and does not allow it.

Comment: This is true. However, if you want, you can specify fbml/iframe on a page basis by using the parameter fb_force_mode in your url.
From the facebook wiki:
For example, if you were using an iframe application, and wanted one page to be rendered as FBML, you could append ?fb_force_mode=fbml to the address, which will cause it to render as FBML. This can be particularly useful when using fb:request-form with iframe applications.